# What's the best way to make communication between two fragments in the same activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

if I have two fragments `FragmentA` & `FragmentB`. `FragmentB` has method like this :

```
void getDataFromFragmentA(string data) {
    Log.e("dataFromA", data);
}
```

if I want to set the data from `fragmentA` can I create instance from `FragmentB` in `FragmentA` and call the method like this :

```
FragmentB fragmentb = new FragmentB();
fragmentb.getDataFromFragmentA("Hello from frag A");
```

is this the best way ? or using interface and if it is not the best way what's the best way and why creating instance is a bad way if it is a bad way ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use interfaces or activity as shared instance. Also you can give a try to datapool.